# How to limit the number of levels created by a density plot and?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, heatmap, r-sp

I have some spatial data and I use the code below to create a heatmap and to extract the created levels as polygons. My question is now how to limit the number of levels which are created? My goal is to have e.g. 5 different density levels?

In a second step I want to extract the polygons which belong to one specific level.  Since I do not have data from a normal distribution as used here in my reproducible example, there might be different polygons with the same density level.

Here is my code up to now:

```
#Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

#create spatial data
lon<-rnorm(10000,mean = 15,sd=1)
lat<-rnorm(10000,mean=45,sd=1)
data <-cbind.data.frame(lon,lat)

#create the heatmap
heatmap <- ggplot(data,aes(x=lon,y=lat))+  stat_density2d(data=data,
                                      aes(x=lon, y=lat,  fill=..level..,
                                        alpha=..level..), geom="polygon")

# build the heatmap without plotting it
gb_heat <- ggplot_build(heatmap)


# extract the polygon specifications
gb_heat_dat <- gb_heat$data[[1]]

# make some polygons!
SpatialPolygons(lapply(unique(gb_heat_dat$group), function(x) {
pts <- gb_heat_dat[gb_heat_dat$group == x,]
Polygons(list(Polygon(as.matrix(data.frame(x=pts$x, y=pts$y)))), as.character(x))
})) -> polys



# plot them
plot(polys)
```

Edit: Thanks to @pHroc's answer I am able to control the number of levels and I also found out how to extract the polygons with the same level. But now I encountered the problem that some created areas are very small ones. Is there a way to control the minimum size of an area or the number of points each and every area should at least contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get at the first part of your question, you can add the argument `bins = 5` to `stat_density2d()`.

```
heatmap <- ggplot(data,aes(x=lon,y=lat))+  stat_density2d(data=data,
                  aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..),
                  bins = 5, geom="polygon")
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a good hint. Is there also an option to define a minimum area for each and every level or to name a minimal number of points within each level?